# What's wrong with this post__not_in argument?

Tags: plugin-development, get-posts

In the script below, the post__not_in argument does not appear to be working unless I hardcode the post ids inside the array(). Anything stand out?

If an item is in the category, but also in the post__not_in, what get's precedent?

get_option('sticky_posts') is a single item array with var_dump = array(1) { [0]=> int(6) }

```
$myposts = get_posts(
                    array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden", 
                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID, get_option('sticky_posts')), 
                        'numberposts' => 10;
                        )
                    );
            foreach($myposts as $idx=>$post){//do something}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$not_in = get_option('sticky_posts');
$not_in[] = $post->ID;
$myposts = get_posts(
                    array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden", 
                        'post__not_in' => $not_in, 
                        'numberposts' => 10;
                        )
                    );
foreach($myposts as $idx=>$post){//do something}
```

hope this helps

Comment: To clarify the original problem, the issue was with the array you were forming Scott, `get_option('sticky_posts')` gives you can array, so in turn your array ended up nesting another array inside it(when `post__not_in` only suppports using a flat array of values). This answer should solve it, so got my +1.. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I was thinking it was something to do with the nested array. I really appreciate the help and explanation.